# Why do Java functional interfaces as parameters usually use contravariant arg type?

Tags: java

Take `java.util.function.Consumer` as an example:

It has a method

```
andThen(Consumer<? super T> after)
```

Most (all?) methods in java.util.function that takes functional interfaces as a parameter use wildcard with super. What advantages does this give?

Comment: Things like System.out::println will be a Consumer<Object>, but make perfect sense for being applied to any type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is less to do with them being functional interfaces, and more to do with *how the parameter is used* within the method.

*Wildcard parameterized types* (unbounded, upper, or lower bounded) allow polymorphism of the parameterized type. This is necessary as `Foo<S>` is not a subtype of `Foo<T>` even if `S` is a subtype of `T`. However a parameter declared as `Foo<? extends T>` can accept both `Foo<S>` and `Foo<T>` where `S extends T`. Similarly `Foo<? super S>` can accept both `Foo<S>` and `Foo<T>` where `S extends T`, but unlike the `extends` form it cannot accept parameterized types where the type argument is a subtype of `S`.

A [*lower bounded wildcard parameterized type*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html) therefore allows the method declaring the parameter to pass items (in this case, of type `T`) as arguments to the method(s) on the parameter (in this case on the interface). This makes sense in the case of `andThen` as the parameter is an "out" parameter <sup>†</sup>: <s>it stores data for use later on, outside the method (either at the calling site, or at a later juncture that the calling site passes the object to)</s> <sup>‡</sup> it allows you to pass data into it (and could potentially transport that data "out" of the method back to the calling site).

In the case of the `Consumer` interface this makes sense. The interface represents a class that `accept`s an item of type `T`. It can be chained with any other `Consumer`, and that could be a `Consumer<P>` where `T extends P`; that means the second consumer can be more general but can still be passed the same item that the first consumer accepted.

This is not possible with [*upper bounded wildcard*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) parameters as these are "in" parameters: they provide data *to* the method to which they are passed. (If the parameter was declared [*unbounded*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html) simply as a `Foo<?>` then it is implicitly upper bounded, by `Object`, so is really no different to an *upper bounded wildcard parameterized type*).

Example:

```
abstract class Animal {}
class Cat extends Animal {}
class Dog extends Animal {}
class Labrador extends Dog {}
```

`andThen(Consumer<? super Dog> after)`:

- can accept `Consumer<Dog>`, `Consumer<Animal>` and `Consumer<Object>`
- inside the method we know we can do `accept(new Dog())` regardless of the type of `Consumer` that is passed in: it will always represent a `Consumer` of a supertype of `Dog` and therefore `accept` a `Dog`

So now we can do:

```
Consumer<Dog> takeToDogKennel = new Consumer<Dog>(); // only for dogs
Consumer<Animal> giveWater = new Consumer<Animal>(); // dogs and cats too
takeToDogKennel 
   .andThen(giveWater)
   .accept(new Labrador());
```

<sup>†</sup> [The Java Tutorials, Guidelines for Wildcard Use](http://%60Foo%3CS%3E%60%20and%20%60Foo%3CT%3E%60%20where%20%60S%20extends%20T%60) explains in/out parameters in more detail.

<sup>‡</sup> Actually `andThen` is a bad example of a method with an "out" parameter - it confuses the issue as it only "operates by side effects" (as per the documentation).

Answer (score 2):

The signature `andThen(Consumer<? super T> after)` suggests that at some point, `after.accept()` will be called with a `T` as a parameter. An implementation of `Consumer<S>` will contain the method `accept(S)`, and if `S` is a superclass of `T`, this method can also be called with a `T`. Therefore, it would make sense to also allow such implementations to be passed.